# Virtual inheritance vs. non-default constructors

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, virtual-inheritance

This code is rejected by (at least) MSVC, ICC, and GCC:

```
class A {
public:
    A( int ) {  }
};

class B: virtual public A {
public:
    //B(): A( -1 ) {  } // uncomment to make it compilable
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

class C: public B {
public:
    C(): A( 1 ) {  }
    virtual void do_something() {  }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    return 0;
}
```

on the basis of

```
error : no default constructor exists for class "A"
    class B: virtual public A {
                            ^
            detected during implicit generation of "B::B()" at line 14
```

Questions:

1. If the code is indeed invalid, how *exactly* does this follow from
   the standard? AFAICT, 10.4/2 and 1.8/4 taken together imply that B
   cannot be a type of the most derived class, and therefore from
   12.6.2/10 we have that B can never, ever call A's constructors.
   (The section numbers are for C++11.)
2. If the code is valid, are compilers violating the standard by
   requiring the presence of constructors they could not possibly call?
   Note that not only they want to call A::A() from B::B(), but they
   want to do it *while compiling C::C()* (double weird).

P.S. This was originally asked on the ICC forum, but posted here due to not being limited to this compiler (and no details forthcoming).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clang shows the error as:

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'B'
    C(): A( 1 ) {  }
    ^
```

12.1/5 says "A defaulted default constructor for class X is defined as deleted if [...] any [...] virtual base class [...] has class type M [...] and [...] M has no default constructor [...]."

Comment: So, both the code is wrong, AND the compiler tries to do the wrong thing with B::B() (as per the original error message). Thanks for the reference, this seems to be the point I was missing.

Comment: @vpozdyayev: Yes, but that would be quite from C++11, while at least some of the compilers/error messages you quoted in your original post are C++03 at best.

Comment: @AndreyT Good point. OTOH, the error message I have quoted comes from ICC 12.1.5 which supports function deletion (manual, anyway).

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to derive a "theorem" from the facts that can be found in the standard, and then you expect the standard to acknowledge the existence of that "theorem". The standard does not do that. It doesn't strive to find and incorporate all possible "theorems" that can be derived from the standard text.

Your "theorem" is perfectly valid (unless I'm missing something). You are right, since class `B` is abstract, this class can never be used as a most derived class. This immediately means that class `B` will never get a chance to construct its virtual base `A`. And that means that technically in `B` the compiler should not care about the availability, and/or accessibility of the appropriate constructors in `A` or in any other virtual bases.

But the standard simply does not make that connection and does not care to make it. It doesn't treat constructors of abstract classes in any special way. The requirements imposed on such constructors are the same as for non-abstract classes.

You can call try suggesting it as a possible improvement to the standard committee.

Comment: +1, interestingly if you go down to the ABI level, the distinction is made (taking Itanium ABI as example), three constructors can be potentially generated for a type: complete, complete allocating, base. The base constructor is the only one that makes sense for a virtual base (as it can never be a complete object) and that constructor will not call the virtual base's constructors... so from a technical point of view, the assumption in the question makes sense and this is an arbitrary restriction (I am not saying that the standard should be changed to allow it, just that it could be done)

Comment: Spot on about theorem proving. I'd love to see this kind of consistency.

Comment: @dribeas Uncommenting the marked line and checking B::B()'s disassembly, I can see something that looks suspiciously like "if A_should_be_initialized_from_B, call A::A(int)". It looks like the compiler prefers to create the single most general constructor, and make base initialization decisions at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 12.6.2/4 prohibits this to me:

> If a given nonstatic data member or base class is not named by a
> mem-initializer-id (including the case where there is no
> mem-initializer-list because the constructor has no ctor-initializer),
> then
>
> — If the entity is a nonstatic data member of (possibly
> cv-qualified) class type (or array thereof) or a base class, and the
> entity class is a non-POD class, the entity is default-initialized
> (8.5)...

It looks to me like that regardless of the class being a virtual base, `B`'s default constructor is still synthesized by the compiler, and such default constructor doesn't know how to construct its `A` base ("the entity is default-initialized (8.5)").